# Fn key behaves like Ctrl-left and Ctrl-left not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

On my laptop, an Elitebook 840, for unknown reasons (after a problem with xorg and an unplugged external screen actually), the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not behave anymore like a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key: I can't change anymore the brightness of the screen using it. Instead, the Fn key behaves like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> ! And the Ctrl-left key does not work anymore ! I would like to go back to the normal setting, Ctrl-left behaving like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key like an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I guess that a configuration file is corrupted somewhere, but which one. Any help ? I use Gnome flashback Metacity.

EDIT (2015-04-20): Something new has happened today. I have plugged an external keyboard having a function key; the function key of the external keyboard works! And I have unplugged the external keyboard: now the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left key</kbd> of the laptop's keyboard behaves like the function key and the function key like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left key</kbd>? Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked under keyboard settings?

Comment: yes of course. It is the thing I did.

Comment: I guess you could get `compiz-config` and remap the keys.

Comment: Using xev, pressing "Fn" displays keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L) and pressing the Ctrl_L key does not display anything anymore... I cannot remap the keys, the Ctrl Left key does not exist anymore :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I unplugged the power cable and removed the battery for a while, everything is back to normal. It seems that this is a known problem for HP laptops which has nothing to do with Ubuntu. I'm posting the answer here in case anyone else has the same problem.